# How readLine works?

Tags: java, readline

```
public class testBuf {
    static String path = "C:/cheaters.log";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = br.readLine();
    int totword = 0;
    while (line != null) {
        String a[] = line.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].length() > 0)
                totword += 1;
        }
        **line = br.readLine();**
    }
    System.out.print("Total number of words" + totword);
    br.close();

}

}
```

I don't understand why we have to write one more code "line = br.readLine" in the loop here? I think it is not necessary but the program will not work when I try to delete it. Please explain it to me ;)

Comment: You could write this more nicely with a do-while statement.

Comment: This is 2015; use [`Files.newBufferedReader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

Answer (score 1):

If you would remove the `br.readLine()`, your while loop would be an infinite one. After all you would be iterating over the same line again and again. With the `readLine()` method, you proceed to the next line till and when there are no more lines left, it returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

**Each method call reads a singular line.**

The first call reads in the first line of the file, and then after it the while loop checks if that line is null. Then, inside of the while loop, the method is called again, and the second line of the file is read in.

Then it returns to the beginning of the while loop and checks if the line is null. If it is not null, the loop runs again, if it is null, meaning that you have reached the end of the file, the loop is not run.

A common abbreviation of this idiom is to read in the lines and assign them to a variable inside of the while loop in a manner similar to the following code:

```
String line = "";
int totword = 0;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String a[] = line.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].length() > 0)
            totword += 1;
    }
}
```

This method of reading solves the problem of having two calls to readLine, because readLine is now being called every cycle of the while loop, and is automatically being checked if it is null.

Answer (score 0):

If the first call to `readLine()` returns a *non-null* value, then the condition inside `while()` will always be `true`. So the program will go into an *infinite* loop.

`br.readLine()` will keep on reading lines. SO you are bound to get a null value when the reading ends and hence you will break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because `readLine()` reads the next line which will checked here : `while (line != null) {`

if you reach the end of the file `readLine()` will return `null`. so if you not call `readline?  inside the loop, you will ever work with the first line.